# how to use if condition in mysql with status = 2

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

create trigger with status with passed with status = 2 and I need to create a tigger after update row second time when del_status = 2

```
CREATE TRIGGER `exchange_log_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `exchange`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT
IF NEW.del_status = 2
INTO
  exchange_log
SET
  client_id = NEW.client_id,
  ex_type = NEW.ex_type,
  segment_type = NEW.segment_type,
  validity_from = NEW.validity_from,
  validity_to = NEW.validity_to,
  file_upload = NEW.file_upload,
  log_status = 'update',
  created_at = NEW.created_at
END IF
END

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NEW.del_status
INTO
  exchange_log
SET
  client_id = NEW.client_id,
  ex' at line 3
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `IF NEW.del_status = 2 THEN INSERT...`

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with PHP. I edited your tags. In future please check you added the right tags, and then your question is more likely to be seen by people with relevant expertise.

Comment: You wouldn't get away with that code in a standalone insert, why would you in a trigger.

Comment: Also I don't see delimiters being set or statements terminated or a begin to match the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `exchange_log_update_new` AFTER UPDATE ON `exchange`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.del_status = 2)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO `exchange_log` 
              values(client_id = NEW.client_id,
              ex_type = NEW.ex_type,
              segment_type = NEW.segment_type,
              validity_from = NEW.validity_from,
              validity_to = NEW.validity_to,
              file_upload = NEW.file_upload,
              log_status = 'update',
              created_at = NEW.created_at);
    END IF;
  END
```